# Python input interpretation as string

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am writing a discord python bot.

I am trying to create a guessing style command for primary colors.

However I am receiving a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` after the user submits their guess.

I was able to solve this with an integer guessing style command with `m.content.isdigit()` however I am hung up on solving this.

I have tried adding `str()` containers around several areas with no joy.

```
elif user_message.lower().startswith('!guesscolor'):
    await message.channel.send('Guess a color of a rainbow')

    def is_correct(m):
        return m.author == message.author and m.content()
    colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo,', 'violet']
    answer = random.choice(colors)
    print(f'The correct color is: {answer}.')

    try:
        guess = await client.wait_for('message', check=is_correct, timeout=5.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return await message.channel.send(f'Sorry, you took too long it was {answer}.')
    if (guess.content) == answer:
        await message.channel.send('You are right!')
    else:
        await message.channel.send(f'Oops, it was actually {answer}.')
        return
    return
```

Any input or direction to solve this is greatly appreciated.

Below is the working version for the integer guess:

```
elif user_message.lower().startswith('!guessnumber'):
   await message.channel.send('Guess a number between 1 and 10')
   def is_correct(m):
       return m.author == message.author and m.content.isdigit()
   answer = random.randint(1,10)
   print(f'The correct answer is: {answer}.')

   try:
       guess = await client.wait_for('message', check=is_correct, timeout=5.0)
   except asyncio.TimeoutError:
       return await message.channel.send(f'Sorry, you took too long it was {answer}.')
   if int(guess.content) == answer:
       await message.channel.send('You are right!')
   else:
        await message.channel.send(f'Oops, it was actually {answer}.')
        return
   return
```

Comment: `m.content()` looks very odd to me. Isn't `m.content` a string? What are you intending to do there?

Comment: You have a comma after `indigo`.

Comment: line 132, in is_correct
    return m.author == message.author and m.content()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: I used the m.content in a previous command for an integer guess. With it I was able to use m.content.isdigit() to convert the response to integer. However doing the same with a str() doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: What are you trying to check about the content in this function?

Comment: The message response containing the color guess. I will add the working version I used for integer in an edit.

Comment: Maybe that should be `m.content in colors`?

Comment: Or `m.content == answer`

Comment: I have added the int version that functions. Sorry I can't seem to get indentations to paste correctly here. I did my best to clean it up though.

Comment: You don't need to do anything to check that it's a string, it's guaranteed to be a string. If you have some other condition on the content, just add that check.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware the response is a string, however the check isn't interpreting it. It is throwing TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check that it's one of the possible colors, do this:

```
   def is_correct(m):
       return m.author == message.author and m.content in colors
```